# Wordpress "download_url" SSL verify

Tags: facebook, wordpress, ssl

Right so I've been working with the Facebook API and can confirm that an image is there and I'm trying to import it to Wordpress to attach it to a post.

Here's the code I have that I'm sure the problem is with.

```
if (!empty($image)){
                $fql ="SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE pid = \"$image\"";
                $fql = urlencode($fql);
                $feedurl = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=$fql&access_token=$page_at";
                $feed=file_get_contents($feedurl);
                $feed = json_decode($feed);
                $image = $feed->data[0]->src_big;

                $tmp = download_url( $image );
                $desc = "SocialHub Facebook Image";
                $file_array['name'] = 'Facebook Image '.$postid;
                $file_array['tmp_name'] = $tmp;
                if ( is_wp_error( $tmp ) ) {
                    @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
                    $file_array['tmp_name'] = '';
                    echo $tmp->get_error_message();
                }
                // do the validation and storage stuff
                $id = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, $postid, $desc );
                // If error storing permanently, unlink
                if ( !is_wp_error($id) ) {
                    set_post_thumbnail( $postid, $id );
                }else{
                    echo $id->get_error_message().'<br>';
                }
            }
```

But when run I get the error message:

```
SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

If anyone can think of a way to download a facebook image without the SSL certificate error, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more thorough workaround.

```
add_filter( 'https_local_ssl_verify', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'https_ssl_verify', '__return_false' );
```

See also:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72529/filter-any-http-request-uri

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, answered my own question; facebook as all the images both with and without SSL so had to simply add:

```
$image = str_replace('https://','http://',$image);
```

Before using the download_url() function

Comment: This is more of a workaround than an answer. If others have this problem and they are accessing a different API that doesn't offer http images, this won't help.